# Importing BBC Food Ontology in Protege 5.5

Tags: import, ontology, protege

I'm trying to import BBC Food Ontology in Protégé version 5.5.0 and I've got the following error:

> org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.OWLOntologyCreationIOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 406 for URL: https://www.bbc.co.uk/ontologies/fo/ at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.loadOWLOntology(OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.java:231) ...

I've also tried with the address of .ttl file https://www.bbc.co.uk/ontologies/fo/1.1.ttl and then got the following error:

> org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.UnloadableImportException: Could not load imported ontology: http://www.bbc.co.uk/ontologies/provenance/ Cause: Server returned HTTP response code: 406 for URL: https://www.bbc.co.uk/ontologies/provenance

It seems that BBC Provenance Ontology which is a requirements for BBC Food Ontology couldn't be imported.

Additionaly, I've tried to import Food Ontology from the local .ttl file which was previously downloaded from the address https://www.bbc.co.uk/ontologies/fo/1.1.ttl. However, the same (above mentioned) error with Provenance Ontology occurred.

Answer (score 0):

A 406 error means that the BBC server has checked the http headers that contain the formats that Protege would accept as a response to a GET on those URLs and it has inferred that it has no response available that fits those parameters. The accept headers set by Protege include a large number of text based formats, so I'm surprised the BBC server doesn't find at least one compatible option.

Using `Accept`:`text/turtle` in a Postman request I can obtain the turtle data from the URL; however, Protege should be including the same accept header in its request, so I cannot explain why that's not working.

Depending on the exact Protege build you're using, it's possible that it might be usong an OWLAPI version with bugs in the accept header creation. You can try and make sure you're using the latest build, or you can update the OWLAPI version Protege uses by downloading the latest `owlapi-osgidistribution` file (for the version 4 releases) from Maven Central and replace the owlapi bundle that's included in you Protege installation. These are drop in replacements, so if the problem is in the OWL API this might solve the issue for you.

Comment: Thank you Ignazio for your answer. It seems that the problem is with the BBC server. I've tried with different options and I got the same error. As a temporary solution, I copied manually those parts of the ontology that I use. Additinaly, I complained to the BBC and got an answer that the BBC ontologies on the website have the old http addresses. However, nowdays all BBC domains are served via HTTPS. They are promissing that necessary modifications will be made in due course.